# How to instantiate only web layer when writing integration tests in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm trying to write integration test for the controller and I need to start only the web context, not the whole application context. The thing is that I'm using old spring boot version - 1.3.1 which doesn't have @WebMvcTest annotation which will be ideal. Do you have any suggestions how to start only the web context or some equivalent to @WebMvTest?

Comment: This article may be helpful https://springframework.guru/unit-testing-spring-mvc-spring-boot-1-4-part-1/

Comment: I've already checked this article, but it's no help. There isn't information about 1.3.1 version that I need. I've tried using @EnableWebMvc annotation and it works but I'm not sure if it's the right solution